I want to install articles from telegra.ph using links and combine them in one pdf file
I want to install articles from telegra.ph using links for this articles and combine them in one pdf file. However, when i try to do it, i have this error:
"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', TimeoutError(10060, 'An attempt to establish a connection was unsuccessful because the required response was not received from the other computer within the required time, or an already established connection was broken due to an incorrect response from an already connected computer', None, 10060, None))"
Here's my sketch that fetches content from Telegra.ph links and combines them into a single PDF file using libraries like requests, BeautifulSoup, and reportlab:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

def fetch_telegraph_content(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
        title = soup.find('title').text
        paragraphs = soup.find_all('p')
        content = '\n'.join([p.text for p in paragraphs])
        return title, content
    else:
        return None, None

def create_pdf(filename, articles):
    c = canvas.Canvas(filename, pagesize=letter)
    width, height = letter

    for title, content in articles:
        c.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 14)
        c.drawString(72, height - 72, title)
        c.setFont("Helvetica", 12)

        # Handle multi-line text
        text = c.beginText(72, height - 100)
        text.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
        text.setTextOrigin(72, height - 100)
        for line in content.split('\n'):
            text.textLine(line)

        c.drawText(text)
        c.showPage() 

    c.save()

def main():
    urls = [
        "https://telegra.ph/1234",
        "https://telegra.ph/123"
    ]

    articles = []
    for url in urls:
        title, content = fetch_telegraph_content(url)
        if title and content:
            articles.append((title, content))
        else:
            print(f"Failed to fetch content from {url}")

    if articles:
        create_pdf("Telegraph_Articles.pdf", articles)
        print("PDF created successfully: Telegraph_Articles.pdf")
    else:
        print("No articles were fetched. PDF not created.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


It is likely that your response(s) with status_code != 200 indicate that you are exceeding the maximum number of requests since you are trying to get all of the articles as fast as possible, many web sites implement such throttling, this is done so that you, and others trying to do the same sort of thing, don't over use the site to the determent of the user experience for other readers.
You can consider printing the error code & message rather than just returning (None, None) so that you can see the errors. In this case it is likely that the response code is 429 and the message is Please refrain from sending too many requests or something similar.
The way to "fix" this issue is to research to find out what rates the server considers to be reasonable, (I have seen mention of 3 requests per 2 seconds but a specific server may have other rate limits or may vary the limit depending on current traffic).
Ideally, to be a well behaved "user", you should examine the header of any 429 response for a retry_after value and then sleep for at least that many seconds before re-trying.
Note that some servers will, in cases where excessive requests are being received and the retry_after value ignored, block your IP address for a period that may be anything up to 24 hours or permanently.
